# Can I change the target and fuction of a button via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

Im trying to change the gameObject that is on the buttons target via Script.
Can really find some code to edit that inside the button.

[image]

I tried to access the button parameters but there is no target parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From script it is a little different than you might expect given the layout presented.
For subscribing use `AddListener` and unsubscribing use `RemoveListener` on the `UnityEvent`.

For a buttons `onClick` event use the following.

```
[SerializeField] private Button button;

private void Awake()
{
    //
    // For Subscribing
    //

    button.onClick.AddListener(OnClickHandler);
    // or
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => { Debug.Log("Anonymous OnClickHandler"); });


    //
    // For Unsubscribing
    //

    button.onClick.RemoveListener(OnClickHandler);

    // Anonymous event handler cannot be removed except by removing all listeners
    button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();

}
private void OnClickHandler()
{
    Debug.Log("OnClickHandler");
}
```